# who knows the volume of Stanford bunny model?

Tags: volume, bunny

I have developed an algorithm to compute the volume of point set.And now I plan to use Stanford bunny model for testing my algorithm,but I haven't found the true value of the volume yet,so I don't know whether the value I computed is accurate.Is there anybody who knows the true volume of  Stanford bunny model?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is an actual concrete answer to this, as the model can be scaled up and down across versions.

Also, for example, my version of the Stanford Bunny doesn't have the bottom properly closed, probably due to the holes because of the hollow porcelain it was modelled off of.

There might be too much variation across the models and its conversions to have one specific value.